# Django return form with errors

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have created two functions, a `edit` and `update`. In the edit view, I return the form, on my template I have a form post to the update function.

I am trying to return the form errors back to the page but how can I do that when it hits the update function? I know I could do all in one function and do a `if request.method == 'POST` but i'd figure to separate them. (Is my solution even the correct way to do in Django?)

My goal is to do a `return redirect with form`, which then form would hold the errors.

```
def locations_edit(request, id):

    location = Location.objects.filter(rand_id = id, user_id = request.user.id).first()

    if location is None:
        print('Error')
        return redirect('company-locations')

    context = {
        'title': 'Edit Location - ' + location.name,
        'pagetitle': 'Editing "' + location.name + '" Location ',
        'tab_name': 'locations',
        'new_location': 0,
        'location': location
    }

    return render(request, 'company/locations/add_edit.html', context)


def locations_update(request, id):

    location = Location.objects.filter(rand_id = id, user_id = request.user.id).first()

    if request.method == "POST" and location is not None:
        form = AddLocationForm(request.POST, instance=location)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            messages.success(request, f'Location {location.name} updated')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return HttpResponse('Error')
            #return redirect('company-locations-edit', id=location.rand_id, *args={'form':form})
    else:
        raise Http404


    return redirect('company-locations-edit', id=location.rand_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `{{ form.errors }}` in your template to show all errors that get in Form.

Answer (score -1):

Django forms handle the form validation errors from their own, please be specific what type of errors you want to show? For your kind information if you want to show any kind of error like 'mentioned details are wrong' or anything else then the method of 'messages' module which you can use is 'messages.error(request, 'etc')' and then return redirect('location').